# How does PHP iterate over mysqli query results?

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm learning to interact with a database in PHP. The code below works, but I do not understand how the loop iterates through `$result`.

```
<?php
  require_once('./login.php');
  $conn = new mysqli($hn, $un, $pw, $db);
  if ($conn->connect_error) die("DIED: CONNECTION FAILED.");

  $query= "SELECT * FROM table1";
  $result = $conn->query($query);
  if (!$result) die("DIED: QUERY FAILED.");

  while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $who = $row['WHO'];
    $what = $row['WHAT'];

    echo <<<_END
    WHO: $who<br>
    WHAT: $what<br>
_END;
  }

  $result->close();
  $conn->close();
?>
```

I understand that while a `$result` element is available, it will be assigned to `$row` and processed in the loop. But how does the interpreter know to move to the next `$result` element?

The code even works when using a for loop instead, such as...

```
$row_count = $result->num_rows;
for($j = 0; $j < $row_count; $j++) {
  $row = $result -> fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

My question boils down to this: how does the interpreter know to use the next element in `$result` without needing something like `$result[$j]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query returns a `mysqli_result`. Per the docs, this object is iterable http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php. So every time you call `fetch_array()`, the result object it is keeping track of which row it is currently on and returning the appropriate result, then moving forward one element in the result set. When there are no more results left, the function returns `null` which is evaluated as `false` thus terminating the loop.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I guess I have to research the meaning of "iterable" in PHP. I thought it meant that I can loop through the object, but apparently there's more to it.

Comment: @Elsewhere You can also use the `fetch_all()` function/method and then loop through it like a normal array via a counter compared to count(array) - http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php